# Application for leave

Tags: sentence

Kindly grant me leave from 14/4/2017 to 20/04/2017 for this I highly obliged to you
Thanks &Regards
Is this the correct sentence to take leave from bos

Comment: this is the first time you've asked for leave, yes?

Comment: No sir this is not a first time when I am leaving

Comment: Are you asking for leave retroactively or in the future?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where you live and work.  "Kindly" is not as frequently used in American work settings as it is in India.

Also, you should add "am" in "I am."  As in, "I am highly obliged to you."

Personally, I would write,

> **Could you please** grant me leave from 14/4/2017 to 20/04/2017? **I would greatly appreciate it.**  Thank you, ...

But I am speaking as someone who works in Chicago, Illinois in the U.S.

Again, it depends on your workplace and culture.  Do whatever is customary in your workplace, if writing it exactly as written is something your boss would understand and appreciate, then it's the correct thing to write.

Answer (score -1):

Having lived in a country for several years where many of the people I know are from Southern Asia, I think the most common way of writing this would be:

"May you/Could you kindly grant me leave from 14/4/2017 to 20/04/2017? For this I would be highly obliged to you. Thank you and Regards."

I think this is a slightly more formal version of what you said, and I have seen similar methods of writing formally from people I know.

Comment: "May you" cannot be used to form a request, only for an undirected expression of wishes.

Comment: @BenVoigt as I said, I was basing this off of what I have seen people from that part of the world write. It is very common for 'may you' to be used in this context, and this is a good example of how 'Indian English' and 'America/British English' are different, hence why they are considered different dialects on most websites that offer the choice (think Siri).